# How to wait until the user finished the tasks after grecaptcha.execute()? reCAPTCHA v2 invisible

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I would like to make my own website, where I
use reCAPTCHA. However, I don't know how to wait after grecaptcha.execute() until the user has completed the tasks. Because now the link is called directly without passing the tasks.
For the rest I use the standard Google Script
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible
It is the reCAPTCHA v2 invisible.

I would be happy about answers.

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
     <script>
       function onSubmit(token) {
         grecaptcha.execute().then(var vslg = document.getElementById("vslg").value;
         window.location.replace("url");
       }
     </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a class="button"></a>
    <div class="topBar">
    </div>
    <div class="underTopBar">
            <form action="JavaScript:onSubmit()" class="flex-itemform form" method="POST" id="formV">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div>
                                <input type="text"  id="vslg" required>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div>
                                <div class="g-recaptcha"
                                  data-sitekey="..."
                                  data-callback="onSubmit"
                                  data-size="invisible">
                                </div>
                                <input type="submit" class="buttonDesign" value="Senden">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    <tr>
                </table>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Possible to see the HTML with form elements and the script tag where you're including the recaptcha api?

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following code does this:

1. The `<button class="g-recaptcha"...` is the [Automatically bind the challenge to a button](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible). It will automatically trigger the invisible recaptcha when the button is clicked.
2. Once the recaptcha is completed it will add a hidden field named `g-recaptcha-response` which contains the token and then run the `onSubmit` callback which submits the form.

```html
  <head>
     <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
     <script>
       function onSubmit() {
         document.getElementById("formV").submit();
       }
     </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a class="button"></a>
    <div class="topBar">
    </div>
    <div class="underTopBar">
            <form class="flex-itemform form" method="POST" id="formV">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div>
                                <button 
                                  class="g-recaptcha buttonDesign"
                                  data-sitekey="..."
                                  data-callback="onSubmit"
                                  data-size="invisible">Senden</button>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    <tr>
                </table>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**Important:** You still need to verify the token `g-recaptcha-response` server side. See [Verifying the user's response](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify). Without verifying the token, adding the recaptcha to the frontend doesn't stop anyone from submitting the form.

Answer (score 1):

I have spent more than 3 hours on this nonsense. It turned out to be a straightforward problem. I hope I can help somebody with this answer.

First, you must realize that you need 2 JavaScript functions.

**1-** A one that is executed after the submit button is pressed. In this function, always use:
`event.preventDefault()` to avoid form submission! You don't want to submit your form yet.
`grecaptcha.execute()` to initiate the reCAPTCHA.

You can execute this function with the submit button (onClick property).

**2-** A one that is executed after the reCAPTCHA is solved successfully. For this function, you only need:
`document.getElementById("form").submit()` to submit your form.

To execute this function, use data-callback property in your reCAPTCHA div element. As you can see in the docs, data-callback property is defined as

> The name of your callback function, executed when the user submits a
> successful response. The g-recaptcha-response token is passed to your
> callback.

That's all you need. Make sure that your form only gets submitted with the second function you created, nothing else.