# Call a javascript function on form submission in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco, recaptcha

Hello Stackoverflow community,

Can someone please share their insights on how can we call a javascript function during form submission in Umbraco frontend and then continue the rest of the workflow ?

Since, I am implementing an invisible recaptcha we have to trigger `grecaptcha.execute();` to generate a client token.

I have to execute this script on form submission so that the recaptcha token gets generated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function  onSubmit(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      grecaptcha.execute();
     }
</script>
```

And then in the `ValidateField` method using

```
 var reCaptchaResponse = context.Request.Form["g-recaptcha-response"].ToString();
```

I can get the client token for validation.

Any leads are appreciated !

So far I have tried checking documentation of SurafceController however, what I want to execute is in frontend not backend.

Edit :

I have added an event listener on form submission. However, when the form is submitted it doesn't wait for the token generation and then in
`ValidateSettings -> context.Request.Form["g-recaptcha-response"]` is null.

Here is my custom field type code.

```
@using Umbraco.Forms.Web
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@model Umbraco.Forms.Web.Models.FieldViewModel
@inject IConfiguration Configuration
@{
    var siteKey = Configuration.GetSection("ReCaptchaEnterprise")["SiteKey"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(siteKey))
    {
        Html.AddFormThemeScriptFile("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js?render=" + siteKey);
        Html.AddFormThemeScriptFile("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render="+ siteKey);
        Html.AddFormThemeScriptFile("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js");
        <div class="g-recaptcha"
             data-sitekey="@siteKey"
             data-size="invisible">
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
                var formContainer = document.querySelector(".umbraco-forms-form");
                var form = formContainer.querySelector("form");
                form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
                    console.log(grecaptcha.execute());
                }) 
            })       
        </script>
    }
    else
    {
        <p class="error">ERROR: reCAPTCHA is missing the Site Key. Please update the configuration to include a value.</p>
    }
}
```

Custom class for the custom field type in Umbraco :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using AngleSharp.Io;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Umbraco.Forms.Core.Enums;
using Umbraco.Forms.Core.Models;
using Umbraco.Forms.Core.Services;
using Request = Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Ocsp.Request;

namespace Crna.ContentManagement.Web.FormsExtensions
{
    public class ReCaptchaEnterprise : Umbraco.Forms.Core.FieldType
    {
        public ReCaptchaEnterprise()
        {
            Id = new Guid(<guid>);
            Name = "ReCaptchaEnterprise";
            Description = "Render a custom reCaptcha enterprise field.";
            Icon = "icon-autofill";
            SortOrder = 10;
            FieldTypeViewName = "FieldType.ReCaptchaEnterprise.cshtml";
        }
        
        // Custom validation in here which will occur when the form is submitted.
        // Any strings returned will cause the submission to be considered invalid.
        // Returning an empty collection of strings will indicate that it's valid to proceed.
        public override IEnumerable<string> ValidateField(Form form, Field field, IEnumerable<object> postedValues, HttpContext context, IPlaceholderParsingService placeholderParsingService, IFieldTypeStorage fieldTypeStorage)
        {
            var returnStrings = new List<string>();

            var reCaptchaResponse = context.Request;
            
            Console.WriteLine("+++++++++++++++++++++ReCaptcha response+++++++++++++++++++++++++++" + context.Request.Form["g-recaptcha-response"]);
            
            // Also validate it against the default method (to handle mandatory fields and regular expressions)
            return base.ValidateField(form, field, postedValues, context, placeholderParsingService, fieldTypeStorage, returnStrings);
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **onsubmit** event to execute Javascript Code e.g.

```
<script>
function doSomething() {
    alert('Form submitted!');
    return false;
}
</script>

<form onsubmit="return doSomething();" class="my-form">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

OR

```
<script>
$('.my-form').on('submit', function () {
    alert('Form submitted!');
    return false;
});
</script>

<form class="my-form">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Reference: [Form Submit Execute JavaScript Best Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082846/form-submit-execute-javascript-best-practice)

Comment: I have managed to do that via document.addEventListener however, when I submit the form it doesn't wait for the recaptcha execution and enters into the ValidateSettings function.

Comment: Check this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73675997

Comment: I have tried with event.preventDefault() however, in that case it doesn't follow the workflow execution and just stops at grecaptcha.execute(). Probably because if the default behaviour is prevented then after generating the recaptcha token what shall it do.